# changing the default url of route in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream, laravel-10

I'm using jetstream in my laravel project and if the routes are exists by default , i want to change the url of login route, as we know the login route returns us to login view but i need to change this route to index route , i want to return the view login when user goes to the index route not to login route. as u know when you are using jetstream there arent the auth folder in controllers that have all routes to change it

i tried to do this route in web file

`Route::get('/', function () { return view('auth.login'); });` 
it takes me to login page when the route is index but now there are 2 routes that take me to the same page and i dont need the second route /login or i need only to change the first from /login to /index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish jetstream files and override routes and etc.

Comment: when i try to do this command php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstreams-views or this php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstreams-controllers i get  INFO  No publishable resources for tag [jetstreams-controllers].

Comment: One way you can make route with `login` url in web.php for example!
After you can show `404` error page or redirect in login route.

Comment: i tried to do this      Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::get('/login', function () {
    abort(404);
});

but when i go to index page i get this error Route [login] not defined.

Comment: Route::get('/login', function () { 
abort(404); 
})->name('login');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).